# SCIM security considerations

Tags: provisioning, scim

I can't find security details that are covering SCIM protocol.
In [SCIM](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-scim-use-cases-01#section-2.3.1) documentation there is only in paragraph 4 :

*Authorization and authentication must be guaranteed for the SCIM
operations.*

When I set REST API (for SCIM) on well known address (according with SCIM protocol) how to control then access ? Everyone can sent SCIM filter request and get response with all resources ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SCIM leaves this aspect to the implementation providers, cause there already many types of mechanisms
to secure a web resource.

Comment: Is there recommended one, like OAuth 2.0 or similar ?

Comment: Yeah, OAuth is preferred, but largely it "depends" on the environment/requirement.